# PHP display image a partir do mysql

Tags: php, mysql, imagem, display

Estou a desenvolver um CMS onde o user pode inserir artigos e se quiser fazer o upload de uma imagem para esse mesmo artigo, os uploads de texto funcionam corretamente mas as imagens não, a unica coisa que aparece é o nome da imagem no sitio onde seria suposto a imagem aparecer, segui a mesma logica que fiz para o upload dos texto (artigos).

PHP:

```
    <?php
session_start();
include_once('../includes/connection.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    // display add page
        if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])) {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $content = $_POST['content'];
        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];

            if (empty($title) || empty($content)) {
                $error = 'Todos os campos têm de ser preenchidos!';
            }

            else {
                $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO articles(article_title, article_content, article_img, article_timestamp) VAlUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');

                $query->bindValue(1, $title);
                $query->bindValue(2, $content);
                $query->bindValue(3, $image);
                $query->bindValue(4, time());

                $query->execute();

                header('Location:index.php');
            }
        }

}
        else {
        header('Location:index.php');
    }
    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>AdminPT</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="../assets/style.css"/>
    </head>

        <body>
            <div class="container">
                CMS
                <br>

                <h4 id ="add">Adicionar Artigo</h4>

                <?php
                if (isset($error)) { ?>
                    <small style="color:#aa0000"><?php echo $error; ?></small>
                <?php } ?>

                <form action="add.php" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input id="title" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Título"/><br><br>
                    <textarea id="content" rows="15" placeholder="Conteúdo" name="content"></textarea>
                    <input type="file" name="image"/><br><br>
                    <input id="addBtn" type="submit" value="Adicionar Artigo"/>
                </form>
                <a id="back" href="../admin">&larr; Voltar</a>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Display imagem (HTML):

```
<div id="news">
            <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>
            <div><h2><?php echo utf8_encode($article['article_title']); ?></h2><div id="newsImg"><?php echo $article['article_img']; ?></div><br><span id="date">Publicado 
                    <?php
                        setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf8', 'Portuguese_Brazil');
                        //setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
                        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');

                        $uppercaseMonth = ucfirst(gmstrftime('%B'));
                        echo utf8_encode(strftime( '%a, '.$uppercaseMonth.' %d de %Y'/* - %H:%M'*/, $article['article_timestamp']));
                    ?></span><p><?php echo utf8_encode($article['article_content']); ?><br><br><span id="print"><a onclick="javascript:window.print();" href="#">Imprimir</a></span><span id="link"><a href="#">Enviar link</a></p></div>
                    <?php } ?>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em vez de

```
$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
```

Você precisa ler o arquivo com

```
$image = file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] );
```

para poder armazenar.

Para mostrar, precisaria de um PHP separado que fizesse o inverso, e colocar este PHP como source da imagem, algo assim:

```
<img src="mostraimagem.php?id=286318936">
```

Entretanto, lembre que estou simplificando o exemplo, antes de mais nada você precisa aprender a usar o BIND correto pra BLOBs, e ter a base de dados preparada para esta quantidade de dados.

o mostraimagem.php seria simples:

```
<?php

//conecte na base de dados antes, e guarde em $con

$query = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $conexao->prepare( $query );
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['id']);
$stmt->execute();

if( $stmt->rowCount() ){
   $resultado = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   header(“Content-type: image/jpg”); //acerte pro tipo de imagem
   print $resultado['article_img'];
   die();
}else{
   //pode servir uma imagem padrão, ou um 404
}

?>
```

A solução ideal seria você reconsiderar todo o sistema e apenas mover o arquivo para uma pasta, e salvar apenas este nome na base de dados, assim evitando uma sobrecarga na base e no processamento do PHP.

Para aprender a fazer isto, um ótimo começo é este:

> **[PHP - Gerenciar o upload de arquivos](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.php)**

Answer (score 0):

Para exibir as imagens com PHP a partir do código da imagem existe a biblioteca GD, da qual você pode utilizar o método [imagecreatefromstring(string $image)](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecreatefromstring.php).

Então para carregar essas imagens você vai precisar criar um arquivo em PHP para carregá-las do banco de dados conforme você as salvou:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$articleID = settype($_GET['id'], 'integer');
$pdo = new PDO("...");
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT article_img FROM articles WHERE article_id = $articleID");

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($row['article_img']);
    imagepng($image);
}

?>
```

Então você chamaria esse arquivo de acordo com o exemplo do outro usuário:

```
<img src="mostraimagem.php?id={article_id}">
```

**Entretanto**, isso não é uma prática muito recomendável, seria mais interessante que tu fizesse o upload do arquivo mesmo, de acordo com [o que é mostrado](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php) no php.net.